# Использование Stream в Map'ах

Tags: java, java-stream

Помогите разобраться плиз.

Есть мапа Map: {params={par1=1, par2=name}}, значение тоже подразумевает тип Map.

Как можно при помощи stream конвертировать значение данной мапы в новую мапу, чтобы получилось {par1=1, par2=name} ?

попытался сделать что-то такое

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = params.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(k -> k.getKey().equals("params"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, v -> v.getValue()));
```

Но все равно итог такой получаю {params={par1=1, par2=name}}

Пробовал продолжать, вызывая снова stream и добавляя map(String::split) например, не получается, в итоге не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следите за тем, что находится в вашем стриме. После `filter` у вас всё ещё стрим, состоящий из `Map.Entry` исходного `Map`'а. Чтобы перейти к стриму из элементов вложенного `Map`'а, нужно его извлечь:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = params.entrySet().stream()
        // Сейчас в стриме [Map.Entry(key=params, value={par1=1, par2=name})]
        .filter(k -> k.getKey().equals("params"))
        // В стриме всё ещё [Map.Entry(key=params, value={par1=1, par2=name})]
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        // Сейчас в стриме [Map {par1=1, par2=name}]
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        // А теперь стриме [Map.Entry(key=par1, value=1}), Map.Entry(key=par2, value=name)]
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Только совершенно непонятно, зачем делаь всё это через стримы. Если вы знаете, что значения исходного `Map`'а - это `Map`'ы, и вы точно знаете, что вам нужен `Map`, лежащий под ключом `"params"`, то почему бы просто его не достать?

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = params.get("params");
```

Если исходный `Map` имеет тип `Map<String, Object>`, но вы точно знаете, что значения - это тоже `Map` - просто сделайте явное приведение типов.